# Android: Build a decoder library from Jpeg to MP4 video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am working on Android 2.2, and my goal is to covert a sequence of images to mp4 video, [MPEG-4_Part_14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14), to be more exact.

The most reasonable solution would be using **FFmpeg** libraries, and compile them to [Android using NDK](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android). How ever I am looking for solution without **NDK**.

I do not expect from you to build this tool for me, or find some one else who did. I spent quit of time now searching for that, and it's some thing that probably no1 one did yet.

So the only thing that I am asking, is help me find the specs so I be able to build the decoder by my self. I know that it's not a trivial task(May be this is why no one did it yet), but I want to do it any way. So please just help me start it.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  The specs you have to [purchase from ISO](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=61490).

Comment: @heavyd Do you know an American site that i can use? I began to see how this is not the best idea. But just curios to read the specs now.

Comment: [ANSI](http://www.ansi.org/) is the US delegate to to the ISO.  You can purchase the the spec from ANSI [here](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ISO%2fIEC+14496-10%3a2012).

Comment: @heavyd tnx, going to look in to it now

Comment: Note that you would have to develop a JPEG decoder and an H.264 *encoder*. That's way more complicated than decoding, since MPEG only specifies how the stream looks like, not the encoding algorithm. Plus, it's going to be slow as hell. You'll be looking at at least a year of development.